# How to get lifetime best seller products

Tags: magento2, rest-api, best-seller

I am creating an API for getting best seller products.

There are a lot answer on community which answering for get best seller on monthly/yearly basis.

I want to get lifetime bestselling product just like Admin dashboard bestseller.

> /vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Dashboard/Tab/Products/Ordered.php

> /vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Dashboard/Grids.php

I looked on above file and they are responsible for Showing bestseller on Admin dashboard But I could not replicate for APIs

Thanks in advance